# Ruby on Rails 4, How to Display User in Another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, routes

I am new to Ruby on rails. I've created basic demo apps by tutorial learning by examples.

Application have three model User,Village and article

Village has many users, Village has many articles, user and article belongs to village

I work , migration work fine

when iam in http://0.0.0.0:3000/villages/1 , i display all user that belong to village 1

**My question is how display in all user in village one this url** **http://0.0.0.0:3000/villages/1/users**

Comment: it in video lynda.com

Comment: anyone want to view all user from particular village, then url http://0.0.0.0:3000/villages/1/users

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to add the url to the routes.rb file under the config folder.

Add line like below

```
resources :villages do
  member do
    get '/user', to: 'villages#show'
  end
end
```

I am assuming that your villages show action is the one that has all the user details displayed.

Answer (score 0):

routes.rb

```
resources :villages do
    member do
      get :users, :articles
    end
end
```

In villages_controller

```
def users
    @village  = Village.find(params[:id])
    @values = @village.users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_data'
end

def articles
    @village  = Village.find(params[:id])
    @values = @village.articles.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_data'
end
```

In show_data.html.erb

```
<% if @values.any? %>
    <% @values.each do |value| %>
       <%= value.name %>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
<%= will_paginate %>
```